# Search by ZonedDateTime

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

guys. Maybe someone can give a clue to solve the problem.
I have a repository method:

```
@Query(value="select * from users where created_at < :date", nativeQuery=true)
List<Users> getUsers(@Param("date) ZonedDateTime date);
```

(in the database the date format is `timestamp(6)`)

When I call this method with `ZonedDateTime.now()` everything works fine.
But when I *change date* and call:

```
List<Users> users = getUsers(ZonedDateTime.now().minusYears(1));
```

it doesn't work. And no matter how to change the date. I also tried to send data as *Instant, Calendar, String, Date* - the result is the same.
Could anyone make a guess why so?

Comment: Because there is no data that adheres to the the date in question?

Comment: @M.Denium no, there is

Comment: Please show the data. It doubt there actually is because else it would have returned data. So are you really sure that there is data with a `created_at` date before the date of (`11-01-2023`) becuase that is what you are requesting herer. Also I have no idea what `timestamp(6)` in your database means or what the database in use actually is.

Comment: @M.Deinum of course, there is the data. if I put `.minusHours(1)` it doesnt search also

Comment: What is the query(and value) that is being executed? What versions are you using? What happens if you use a `java.sql.TimeStamp` instead does that work? Still no mention of database or what `timestamp(6)` means for your database.

Comment: When there is a question of the data existing do not tell me it exists, **show me**.  Run a `select ...` that gets the data you should be processed.